# Why this is a memory leak?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

The following [article](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/c-cplusplus/what-is-a-memory-leak-in-c/) explains memory leaks. I wonder why the following code causes a memory leak.

```
  int *data = new int;
  *data = 15;
```

When I create `data` and assign 15, then as much as I understand 15 is being copied to the memory `data` So we still have a pointer that points to `data` and we can `delete` it.

I think a memory leak would be `data = 0x00123` for example, right? Here we already lost the control over the memory, and memory is really wasted.

Any thoughts?

Comment: The leak is if `delete` is never called on the pointer pointed to by `data`, copying `15` is not an issue.

Comment: You know the article tells you exactly why it a leak right below the code.  Also the code as is is not a memory leak as we have no context where it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're reading selectively.

quote from the original site you linked:

> Out of Scope Pointer

```
void memLeak( )
{
  int *data = new int;
  *data = 15;
}
```

in this example there is a memory leak since no one deleted `data` and it becomes not-reachable after `memLeak`

this snippet:

```
int *data = new int;
*data = 15;
```

is not a memory leak by itself

Answer (score 3):

You have to take into account the full context of that code:

```
void memLeak( )
{
    int *data = new int;
    *data = 15;
}
```

In that context, as soon as the function returns, you no longer have access to the pointer, so there will be no way to recover the memory allocated to that pointer.

Answer (score -1):

On a separate note, `data = 0x00123` is much worse than memory leak. It is *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: Why, if I am not accessing that memory?

Comment: This is incorrect.  You can assign anything you want to a stack variable.

Comment: @Narek, because that becomes an invalid pointer. And standard is pretty strict about invalid pointers.

Comment: @Aenimated1, who told you so? You can read about invalid pointers. After that, you can retract your misconstrued downvote.

Comment: Which standard are you referring to?  There is no undefined behavior until you attempt to dereference an invalid pointer.  And in some [admittedly contrived, toy] architectures, 0x00123 may even be a valid memory location to reference.

Comment: Incidentally, I didn't downvote this answer for that reason.  I downvoted it because the answer isn't useful.  From the original post, it's clear that Narek didn't believe this was a good idea - it was used as an example of losing the reference to the allocated memory.